# Ошибка в VirtualBox "FATAL: No bootable medium found" при загрузке из vdi

Tags: linux, virtualbox, boot

На флешке есть установленный Linux Mint (не LiveCD, UEFI), в Windows 10 сделал из раздела dsk, с помощью утилиты VirtualBox конвертировал в vdi, подключил как жесткий диск, при загрузке VM пишет

> FATAL: No bootable medium found. System halted

Подключал LiveCD, делал update-grub, не помогло. Как правильно настраивать такую систему?

Comment: Ну а с dsk грузится?

Comment: Установленный-то под BIOS или под UEFI?

Comment: Установленный-то под под UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте включить UEFI в настройках виртуальной машины.